# Bind_result can't be used in prepared() query

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I want to use a variable from a bound result in another query but I get an error saying the result is non object.

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in

```
$stmt =mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT DISTINCT COL1 from TABLE1 WHERE COLID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $SOMEID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($COL1);


while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $stmt1 =mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT COLA from TABLE2 WHERE COLID = ?");
            $stmt1->bind_param("s", $COL1);
            $stmt1->execute();
            $stmt1->bind_result($COLA);
            $stmt1->fetch();   
            if (!$COLA)
                    {
                    echo $COLA;    
                    }

                    }
```

How do I use `$COL1` to select `$COLA`?

Comment: use `or die($link->error)` on prepare to check for errors

Comment: This means the second `mysqli_prepare` is getting an error.

Comment: Why are you doing two separate queries instead of just joining the two tables?